# What does it mean when both parents are the same changeset?

Tags: mercurial

`hg log` reports the following:

```
changeset:   16:30c4e3529965
parent:      14:b8c4717e6eb9
parent:      14:b8c4717e6eb9
user:        talented_user
date:        Fri Nov 04 14:25:26 2011 -0500
summary:     Merge
```

Both parents are revision 14. I don't know how our talented_user managed this. I've never seen it before, but that might be just because I normally use TortoiseHg, and don't spend all day looking at actual numbers of parents/children. I'm unable to replicate it. You don't even want to see what TortoiseHg tried to do with the graph, and hgweb.cgi gave error 500 when attempting to graph it.

I couldn't find anything on google about it at all. Am I missing something really obvious?

Comment: Possibly some manual editing using `hg debugsetparents`

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a bug, possibly caused by rebase. [This issue](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/bts/issue3085) shows the same problem.

Comment: Thanks for the link. The user who performed this is a guy who wants as little to do with Mercurial as possible. He just commits and pushes, and leaves management up to everyone else. Unless TortoiseHg makes it really easy to accidentally rebase something, I don't think that's what he was doing :)